# SSIS created in Visual Studio 2019 not working from an application created in Visual studio 2010

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019

I have an application created in Visual Studio 2010 which use to run SSIS(created in 2008 BIDs) and many different process. We have upgraded to Visual studio 2019 and creating the SSIS in VS 2019. The new SSIS created in 2019 are not loading from application created in Visual Studio 2010.

-****- Error: - Ex Message:The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

I am getting this error message.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why *should* it work? The components, the schema and even the project system itself are completely different. The error says that the old Visual Studio can't even read the new XML schema

Comment: Besides, SSIS projects are run by SQL Server, not Visual Studio. No supported SQL Server version (ie 2016 and later) would be able to run a 2008 SSIS project. Even SQL Server 2014 would require a migration

Comment: Why use Visual Studio 2008 at all? You can edit SSIS files even in the free Visual Studio Community editino